# "AndroidHttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type" error in ksoap2

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

This is in eclipse for an android app. I am using ksoap2 to access a function in an online wsdl. While making a soapobject() to do that, I am coming across this error. I have added the ksoap2 jar file in build path and all the rest of the code related to ksoap2 is working perfectly. I tried a google search, but found nothing. So how to prevent this error?

Comment: Prefer URL.

Here is good example in question of your answer...

[Nice Example of Ksoap2 request in android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196387/create-soap-envelope-with-security-header-in-android-using-ksoap2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`AndroidHttpTransport` is Replaced By  `HttpTransportSE` Now.

you can Use `HttpTransportSE` as Below Way :

```
HttpTransportSE HttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(YOUR_URL);
```

Hope it will Work for you.