# Error When calling asp.net web service through android

Tags: android, ksoap2

such as E/dalvikvm(2193): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport', of android httpTransport and what to write in place of "input"  request.addProperty("input", searchNameString); I want to get the result by calling web service to the android app but I could not able to display it please help me on how to retrieve result from the webservice and also how to display to the android app. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer URL which is post question by me.

[create soap envelope with security header in android using ksoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196387/create-soap-envelope-with-security-header-in-android-using-ksoap2)

If your ksoap2 library is not working fine then change another kshoap2 library.

You use AndroidHttpTransportSE instead of AndroidHttpTransport.

Comment: It is working but not getting how to call androidhttptransport

Comment: May be this is library problem. Change library.