# Issue with Ksoap when i trying t connect to my webservice

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2

I am trying to connect to my webservice via ksoap and giveme this error

> cannot find dispatch method for {}

I know that are 2 question with the same error in both they are not putting the namespace correctly or adding the correct method name, here i am adding the correct namespace, and the correct method also it was working now is not, that's the problem, here is the code that call the webservice

> ObjConexion object = new ObjConexion();

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(object.NameSpace(), "login");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();



    /*PropertyInfo namePro =new PropertyInfo();
    namePro.setName("_name");
    //namePro.setValue(extras.getString("name"));
    namePro.setValue("sdfasdfsadf");
    namePro.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(namePro);
    */
    PropertyInfo emailPro =new PropertyInfo();
    emailPro.setName("email");
    //emailPro.setValue(extras.getString("mail"));
    emailPro.setValue("asdfsdfasdfasdf");
    emailPro.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(emailPro);

    PropertyInfo passwordPro =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordPro.setName("password");
    //passwordPro.setValue(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd)).getText().toString());
    passwordPro.setValue("asdkasdkfkasdf");
    passwordPro.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordPro);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("WSDLPath");
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();   

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not enter method name:

```
androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
```

Enter method name:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(METHOD_NAME, envelope);
```

Prefer following url where you get your answer.  This question is asked by me.  After had solve it and I put answer to use for others.

[create soap envelope with security header in android using ksoap2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196387/create-soap-envelope-with-security-header-in-android-using-ksoap2)